# Run Ubuntu Touch in chroot container on Android

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, chroot, container

On my Fairphone 4 I got Ubuntu running in a chroot container using Linux Deploy.

I'd like to try out Ubuntu Touch, but I don't want to wipe my phone just to do that.

Is it possible to either run Ubuntu Touch in a container or install Ubuntu Touch on top of my existing Ubuntu installation in the container? As in, use Ubuntu Touch as the GUI for my Ubuntu in a container?

I am hoping that this allows me to use my Ubuntu installation on the phone better, since Ubuntu Touch offers an actual Linux OS with mobile GUI.

Comment: Ubuntu Touch is no longer owned or maintained by Canonical . Ubuntu Touch is a mobile version of the Ubuntu operating system, being developed by the UBports community. Contact them for any issues you may have.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Ubuntu Touch is now a UBPorts product - refer https://ubports.com/ or the ubuntu-touch tag you used*